# Hide div if database contains value - Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, angular

I want to check if a MySQL database contains a specific value. If it is true I want to hide a HTML `<div>`. Is this possible?

Can I hide elements with CSS & JS, or what should I use to hide the div?

Also, How would we add it in the Div like a NgIF statement

Thanks!

Comment: PHP itself does not interact with elements. It simply outputs HTML, which is parsed as elements. You can prepare a conditional class attribute on an element via PHP as part of the output. It sounds like you need to learn some PHP basics.

Comment: Echo the element ONLY IF the database has the targeted value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this in your PHP file. I have included an example of an item that is always rendered, and something that is conditionally rendered.

```
<div id="userinfo">
    <?php // This is always rendered by the server ?>
    Username: <?php htmlentities($row['username']) ?>

    <?php // This is rendered by the server if the column is true ?>
    <?php if ($row['admin']): ?>
        <div class="admin">(admin)</div>
    <?php endif ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you all! I think halfers answer is the best for me.

Comment: You're welcome @devlog. If you're interested, there is a PHP tutorial in my profile that might be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are seriously thinking about hiding the element with JavaScript (due to some kind of restriction or requirement). You can use following method.

**CSS + Javascript + PHP way:**

If you are thinking more like the Run code snippet section in Stack Overflow. Show expanded ONLY if it is set in database.

Then in that case you can implement something like this

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btnToggle").on("click", function() {
    $("#comments").toggleClass("hide");
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Hide using CSS way. Hide class can be echoed from your PHP based on the database value -->
<button type="button" id="btnToggle">Toggle hide/show</button>
<div id="comments" class="hide">Comment section to hide</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along the line of

```
if (your statement condition) {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById(DIV_ID").style.display= "none";</script>';
  exit;
}
```